# How do i put XMMATRIX inside XMFLOAT4X4

Tags: directx11, matrix, c++

I'm currently trying to move my weapon with the camera. To do this i'm creating a vector (`tempVect`) where i load how much the camera has moved compared to the weapon (in the code behind is just filled with random values to test it). `TempTranslation` is the `XMMATRIX` where the translation is stored. result is `the XMMATRIX` that comes out from the multiplication of `tempMatrix` and tempTranslation. `mPistolWorld` is an `XMFLOAT4X4` that is going to be loaded into the "world" variable to make the `world * view * proj` matrix. Now that i have `result` how can i load it into `mPistolWorld` ?

```
XMVECTOR tempVect = XMVectorSet(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0);

    tempTranslation = XMMatrixTranslationFromVector(tempVect);

    XMMATRIX tempMatrix = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mPistolWorld);

    XMMATRIX result = XMMatrixMultiply(tempMatrix, tempTranslation);
```

Comment: If you are finding DirectXMath's strict requirements for alignment difficult to work with, consider using the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). The ``SimpleMath::Matrix`` class uses C++ constructors and operators to invoke the required load/store functions automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to update the mPistolWorld XMFLOAT4X4 variable using:

```
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mPistolWorld, result);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.storing.xmstorefloat4x4(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there any equivalent to this which doesn't require an intermediary variable?